# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in JQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQuery-UI datepicker as shown below:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var holidayDays = [];
  var weekendInclusives;
  var holidayInclusives;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
    var air_id = $(this).val();

    var a = $(this).parent();

    var op = "";

    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '{{ route('
      get.leavecounts.all ') }}',
      data: {
        'id': air_id
      },
      dataType: 'json', //return data will be json
      // console.log("Its Change !");
      success: function(data) {
        $('#weekendinclusive').val(data.weekendinclusive);
        $('#holidayinclusive').val(data.holidayinclusive);
        holidayDays = data.nationalholidays;
        weekendInclusives = parseInt($("#weekendinclusive").val());
        holidayInclusives = parseInt($("#holidayinclusive").val());
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });
  });
}); <
/script>
```

Then, I tried to use if statements based on the values of the functions:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var holidayInclusives = $('#holidayinclusive').val();
     var weekendInclusives = $('#weekendinclusive').val(); 
    $("#leave_days").on('keyup blur', function(e) {
      var periodval = parseInt($("#leave_days").val());
      holidayDays = holidayDays;
      var startDate = $('.commencement_date');
      var endDate = $('.resumption_date');

      var dte = startDate.datepicker("getDate");
      dte.setDate(dte.getDate() + periodval);
      endDate.datepicker("setDate", dte);
    });

    function noWeekendsAndHolidays(date) {
      var ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
      //if u have to disable a list of day
      var removeDays = holidayDays;
      console.log(ymd);
      if ($.inArray(ymd, removeDays) >= 0) {
        return [false];
      } else {
        //Show accept sundays
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5)];
      }
    }

    function noHolidays(date) {
      var ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
      //if u have to disable a list of day
      var removeDays = holidayDays;
      console.log(ymd);
      if ($.inArray(ymd, removeDays) >= 0) {
        return [false];
      }
    }

$('.commencement_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: 1,
    setDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
            return noWeekendsAndHolidays(date);
        }
        else if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 1) {
            return noHolidays(date);
        }
        else if (weekendInclusives == 1 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
            return $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        }
    }
});

    $('.resumption_date').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',
      minDate: +1,
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
      yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
      enableOnReadonly: true,
      beforeShow: function(i) {
        if ($(i).attr('readonly')) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      // disabled: true,
      // beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

Then I got this error:

> create:990 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

and it points at:

```
  if (weekendInclusives = 0 && holidayInclusives = 0) {
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsAndHolidays;
  }
  else if (weekendInclusives = 0 && holidayInclusives = 1) {
    beforeShowDay: noHolidays;
  }
  else if (weekendInclusives = 1 && holidayInclusives = 0) {
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends;
  },
```

When I changed the '=' to '==', the error changed to:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=='

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the line of code in question?

Comment: @FSDford - It is the IF Statement inside this datepicker:    $('.commencement_date').datepicker({

Comment: You can't have an `if`/`else` inside an object declaration like that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - What do I do? And what's the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if` statements inside an object declaration like that.  You'll need to create the object as its own variable, then you can use your `if` to set properties.  Then you can pass that object to `datepicker()`.

```js
let dateOpts = {
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: 1,
    setDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
};

if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
    dateOpts.beforeShowDay = noWeekendsAndHolidays;
}
else if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 1) {
    dateOpts.beforeShowDay = noHolidays;
}
else if (weekendInclusives == 1 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
    dateOpts.beforeShowDay = $.datepicker.noWeekends;
}

$('.commencement_date').datepicker(dateOpts);
```

---

UPDATE: If you want to update the datepicker when the `weekendInclusives` or `holidayInclusives` variables update, then you'll need to have `beforeShowDay` check for this.

```
$('.commencement_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: 1,
    setDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
            return noWeekendsAndHolidays(date);
        }
        else if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 1) {
            return noHolidays(date);
        }
        else if (weekendInclusives == 1 && holidayInclusives == 0) {
            return $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @RocketHamzat - I got this error:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. But when I remove the IF statement, the error disappears. What di I do?

Comment: @user11352561 You probably have a syntax error elsewhere.  You'll need to check the rest of your code, you may have a missing `}` or `;` or something somewhere.

Comment: @RocketHamzat -Each time  $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {   is initiated, the values of weekendInclusives and holidayInclusives in the  if statement did not change. Please help me out

Comment: @user11352561 This code runs when the page loads and sets up the datepicker based on whatever values were set at that point in time.  Now that code is done running.  When your change event is ran, the variables (`weekendInclusives` and `holidayInclusives`) may be updated, but the datepicker doesn't know that, it's already been set up.

Comment: @user11352561 What you probably want to to is set `dateOpts.beforeShowDay` to a function that checks the variables.  Something like: `dateOpts.beforeShowDay = function(date) { if (weekendInclusives == 0 && holidayInclusives == 0) { return noWeekendsAndHolidays(date); }};`.

Comment: @RocketHamzat - Pleae can you help attend to:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804193/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-startdate-getdate-is-not-a-function

Comment: @RocketHamzat   Kindly Pardon me:  How do I now add this code you gave me above:      dateOpts.beforeShowDay = function(date) { if...           to what I initially have:

Comment: @RocketHamzat - Thanks so much. Can you assist me with this?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804193/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-startdate-getdate-is-not-a-function

Comment: @RocketHamzat - Where and when do I declare   var holidayInclusives = $('#holidayinclusive').val(); and var weekendInclusives = $('#weekendinclusive').val();   It's still not loading the value according to $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {

Comment: @RocketHamzat - Its like Its  Not implementing the if statement

Comment: @RocketHamzat - Its like Its Not implementing the if statement. I mean, its still not seeing It's not seeing weekendInclusives and holidayInclusives

Comment: @user11352561 They need to be declared outside of the function (and outside of the event).  Right after the `$(document).ready()` should work. `$(document).ready(function() { var weekendInclusives = 0, holidayInclusives = 0; })`.

Comment: @RocketHamzat - It works fine. Thanks.   Any luck on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804193/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-startdate-getdate-is-not-a-function?